# Как прибавлять новое значение в Label?

Tags: swift, xcode

У меня имеется 13 ViewController'ов в проекте, я передаю данные из 13-ого View в 7-ой View, то есть обратная передача данных.

В `PickerView` я записываю выбранные данные в переменную:

```
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    volumeFromMilimetersVC = String(volume.volumeArray[row])
   }
```

Код из контроллера, откуда я передаю данные:

```
var volumeFromMilimetersVC = ""

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc = segue.destination as? MainViewController
    vc?.delegate = self
    vc?.currentValue.text = volumeFromMilimetersVC + " " + "/"
}
```

В `currentValue.text` я записываю значение, которое пользователь выбрал на последнем View. Один раз оно срабатывает и записывается. Далее, мне нужно, чтобы то первое значение сохранилось в Label и когда пользователь второй раз выбирает новое значение, оно прибавлялось к предыдущему значению в лейбле. Допустим, пользователь выбрал 100 - значение записалось в Label на предыдущем View. Пользователь выбирает еще значение, например, 500 и значение в Label должно быть 600 (500 + 100) и так далее.

UPD. Я создал модель для сохранения в UserDefaults, но как использовать данные для сложения не пойму

```
    static var addedVolume: String! {
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: SettingsKeys.addedVolume.rawValue)
    } set {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let key = SettingsKeys.addedVolume.rawValue
        if let userAddVolume = newValue {
            print("Объем напитка \(userAddVolume) добавлен в \(key)")
            defaults.set(userAddVolume, forKey: key)
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        } else {
            defaults.removeObject(forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать примерно так

В целевом вью контроллере (7-й) добавляем такой код

```
private var volume: Double = 0 {
    didSet {
        updateVolumeLabel(with: volume)
    }
}

public func addVolume(_ value: Double) {
    volume += value
}

private func updateVolumeLabel(with value: Double) {
    // форматируем и выводим текст в лейбле
    let text = String(value)
    // ...
}
```

В исходном (13-й) тогда делаем например так

Если изменить тип переменной

```
var volumeFromMilimetersVC: Double = 0

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    volumeFromMilimetersVC = volume.volumeArray[row]
}

vc?.addVolume(volumeFromMilimetersVC)
```

Comment: Идеально! Огромное спасибо!

Comment: не подскажете, как сделать, чтобы после перезапуска приложения, к лейблу можно было продолжать складывать новые значения? Я сделал, что сейчас в лейбле сохраняются выбранные значения при первом запуске. `DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.currentValue.text = UserSettings.addedVolume
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()  }` При повтором запуске и добавлении нового значения, лейбл не складывает значения к предыдущему сохраненному, а полностью его перезаписывает

Comment: @Kenton при запуске присваивать значение наподобие `volume = Double(UserSettings.addedVolume)`, при выходе из вью контроллера или приложения записывать значение volume обратно в UserSettings.addedVolume